# Laptop-connected VGA monitor is mirror only, not independently detected. 14.04

Tags: multiple-monitors

I know this is a common occurrence but I can't detangle the error. This connection has previously worked, but between then and now (12 months perhaps), I tried to get steam running and may have messed with my drivers (I'm on integrated intel HD graphics). Any advice would be appreciated.

Some info:

```
sudo lspci -v
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 103d
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 41
        Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
        Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        I/O ports at e0e0 [size=8]
        Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
        Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
        Capabilities: [a4] PCI Advanced Features
        Kernel driver in use: i915


xrandr -q
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1600 x 900, current 1600 x 900, maximum 1600 x 900
default connected primary 1600x900+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1600x900        0.0*
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the system settings in the top-right corner of your screen
2. Click on "screen display"
3. Turn off mirroring

### Done!

**;-)**